# Need form to stay on top of parent only

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, winapi

I have a multi-window application. My main form is a child of the desktop. My application can create other forms that also become children of the desktop. However, I have a special case where my main form needs to create a form that will always stay on top of it.

I had this working to an extent....however, if I then create other windows in the application this form seems to stay on top of even these!

So basically what I need to know is...

How can I create the form from my main form and make it stay on top of my main form only? Is it possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f: TForm;
begin
  f := TChildForm.Create(Self);
  f.PopupMode := pmExplicit;
  f.PopupParent := Self;
  f.Show;
end;
```

Bye.

Comment: Was actually just about to award the correct answer to Craig Stuntz as he was correct, but he removed for some reason! Thanks.

Comment: I removed it because I'm less than completely confident that it works correctly with modeless forms (I don't use modeless popups that much). If it works, though, great!

Comment: James, Craig Stuntz replied you the same?

Comment: Yeah, he said I had to set the PopupMode to explicit and the PopupParent to the main form.

Comment: Where has this solution been my whole life?!

Comment: The only downside I see is that the other form receives focus, and the main form loses focus. Currently working to see if I can overcome that.

Comment: You can also just set the PopupMode to pmAuto if you want it to stay on top of the form it is being created from.